# Запись результата в файл H.txt

Tags: c

Чет туплю, как записать результат в файл.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int a, b;
  int r = scanf ("%d%d", &a, &b);
  assert (r == 2);
  printf ("%d\n", a + b);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Надо открыть файл с помощью функции fopen и записать туда данные, например, используя fprintf

Comment: Как я понимаю, полученный результат тянет не меньше, как на Нобелевскую премию, и его обязательно нужно записать в скрижали истории Человечества!

Answer (score 5):

В принципе, код модифицировать для этого и не нужно :) Достаточно запустить получившуюся в результате компиляции программу с перенаправлением стандартного вывода в файл:

```
./program > H.txt
```

Если же этого не устроит, то есть как минимум два варианта:

1. [man fopen](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=fopen&category=3&russian=), [man fwrite](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=fwrite), [man fprintf](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=fprintf)
2. [man open](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=open), [man write](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=write)

Answer (score 2):

Если это для решения олимпиадной задачи, то

```
freopen("h.txt", "w", stdout);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну, и, наконец, то что скорей всего вам нужно.:)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main( void )
{
    FILE *fp;
    int a, b;

    int r = scanf ("%d%d", &a, &b);
    assert( r == 2 );

    fp = fopen( "H.txt", "w" );      
    assert( fp != NULL );      

    if ( fp )
    {
        fprintf ( fp, "%d\n", a + b );
        fclose( fp );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Лучше вычислять результат как имеющий тип `long long int`,  и записать

```
        fprintf ( fp, "%lld\n", ( long long int )a + b );
```

так как сложение двух целых чисел одного типа может привести к переполнению.

Comment: Если первый `assert` ещё чем-то можно оправдать (но сомнительно...), то второй уж точно нечем :)

Comment: @PinkTux Заблуждаетесь. assert  дезактивируется директивой препроцессора NDEBUG в конечной версии. программы А на этапе отладки он полезен в качестве средства сообщения об ошибке.

Comment: Вот про `NDEBUG` я и говорю. Чем хорошо что в релизной версии никакой диагностики не будет в случае ошибки? В моих пампасах такой код просто ревью не пройдёт. А если будет часто повторяться - можно и канделябром отхватить :-)

Comment: @PinkTux В релизной версии после того, как он проверит, что файл создается, он может добавить более совершенную систему диагностики с помощью предложения if. :) А пока нам неизвестно, что он собирается делать в случае возникновения ошибки открытия файла.

Comment: Боюсь, что человек, не знающий про `fopen`, может скопипастить код как верный во всём, и даже не догадаться, что assert может исчезнуть :-)

Comment: @PinkTux  Показанный код как раз удовлетворяет текущему дизайну программы.